# WSO2 Roles and Permissions for use in web application

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I understand that user and roles in wso2is are use for management the carbon console, how can i use roles and permissions for use in my web app, for example, defined roles and permission and apply policies using xacml ?

Comment: Refer to the following documents:https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-access-control-policy-for-a-service-provider/. https://medium.com/@buddhimau/role-based-authorization-for-spring-boot-using-wso2-identity-server-3d74ab307fb9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this [documentation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-access-control-policy-for-a-service-provider/) to set up role-based authorization for your application.

For the permission-based authorization, you can assign those permissions to the role and achieve it.